# Raster Menu disappeared in QGIS 3.22.3 on Win10

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, extract, windows-10

I was using QGIS 3.18 to chop up some GeoTIFF files today. I came back to re-jig the files, and found that the Raster menu was missing all the sub-menus, which includes the Extraction menu items that I was using to chop the GeoTIFFs. I thought I was going nuts, so I uninstalled, re-installed, moved to version 3.22, but still no menu sub-menus under Raster, just "Raster Calculator", "Align Rasters" and "Georeferencer".

How do I get the missing extraction menu items back?  Is there alternative way to chop GeoTIFFs into smaller chunks?

Comment: Check if the Processing Extension is activated:  Plugins -> Manage and Install Plugins -> Installed, look for "Processing" and check if it's enabled

Comment: It was installed but there was no check mark beside it.  I ticked the box, and voila, my menu options are back!  Thanks.  Do you want to add as an answer and I can accept as solution?  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if the Processing Extension is activated:

```
Plugins -> Manage and Install Plugins -> Installed
```

look for "Processing" and check if it's enabled

[image]